# How to implement different UI screens to my playground

Tags: swift, user-interface, swift-playground

Im trying to include a tap to open screen on my playground that then allows users to see my chart. I want them to first tap through 3 or 4 screens with different information before loading to my main page.

Ive tried searching up tutorials (Im new at this), but cant find any that help me.

So this is the code to show my table view and need help implementing the tap screens

```
class HOCMasterViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return reasons.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell!
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
```

My table appears, just need to add the UI for the tap screens!

Answer (score 0):

First of all the information screens that you need users to tap through. How are they being displayed? Are you using simple UIViews? Kindly give us some info on that? If you are using different UIViews on which you are showing information, then I would simply hide the previous UIView/ remove it from superView and add the next UIView and so on!

So your playground loads and when you tap on the screen by using a UITapGestureRecognizer and in the selector function you count the taps and according to each tap, you can hide or show the UIViews / or animate the constraints / frames of each UIView. Then after 3 taps you can show the TableViewController.

Kindly provide us with the information screen code.

Comment: Yes so I should have rephrased my question a bit. As I said Im just starting out and also need help setting up new UIViews